# Change the color of a div back and forth on click

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a homework assignment to change the color of this this div back and forth on click

```
<div id = "color-block">
    <p id="center-text">The color is: <span id = "color-name">#F08080</span> </p>
</div>
```

So far I have this, which changes the color once, but then will not change it back to the original color

```
document.getElementById("color-block").onclick = function () {
  changeColor();
};
function changeColor() {
  if (
    (document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor = "#f08080")
  ) {
    document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor = "#008080";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor = "#f08080";
  }
}
```

I'm unsure of what is causing the else statement to not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. For comparisons you use `==` (equality) or `===` (identity). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals#a_real_example

Comment: Here's example code of how to build this following best practices: https://jsfiddle.net/s6coeuw9/ (for instance this code allows you to add one more color at the top of the script and the rest will just work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (I'm not sure why) HEX colors (e.g. #ff0000) get converted to RGB colors (e.g. rgb(255,0,0)). It's therefore easier to just use RGB colors. There was also a fault in your *if*. You have to use a == for comparisons. You code ends up being like this:

```
document.getElementById("color-block").onclick = function () {
  changeColor();
};
function changeColor() {
  if (
    (document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(240, 128, 128)")
  ) {
    document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 128, 128)";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("color-block").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(240, 128, 128)";
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d174aj95/